# Remap right ctrl to behave like left ctrl? (currently typing stuff like æ ß ¶)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

As explained in the title my right control key is behaving oddly. It types characters like æ ß ŋ. I'd like it to simply toggle the control mode, like the left one.

I gave xmodmap a shot using the following code:

clear·control

add·control·=·Control_L·Control_R

And ran the file, but it's still not working.

Any idea? Thanks.